# Skipping bytes with the Jackson JsonParser

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I currently have a FileInputStream that I know contains interleaved objects (Metadata.class and BigInfo.class) in json format, ordered like:

[Metadata1, BigInfo1, Metadata2, BigInfo2, Metadata3, BigInfo3, ...]

I'm using Jackson's JsonParser to read these like parser.readValueAs(Metadata.class) and parser.readValueAs(BigInfo.class).

One thing I'd like to take advantage of is that the Metadata objects contain the length of the following serialized BigInfo objects, as well as whether I need to read it or not. So I want to be able to skip the appropriate number of bytes corresponding to a BigInfo object, if I don't need to read it:

```
Metadata metadata = parser.readValueAs(Metadata.class);
// Whether I need to read the BigInfo object that comes after
boolean mustRead = metadata.isMustReadBigInfo();
if (!mustRead) {
    // Size of the bigInfo object that comes after
    int bigInfoSize = metadata.getBigInfoSize();
    parser.skip(bigInfoSize); // This 'skip' method is needed
}
```

I can achieve "skipping" by using parser.skipChildren(), but this will read (and discard) all bytes of the inputStream sequentially, and will be comparatively much slower than the underlying FileInputStream's 'skip' method, which makes use of a random access 'seek' into a position in the file.

I've tried calling 'skip(bigInfoSize)' on the parser's underlying inputStream. However, this doesn't work since JsonParser reads and stores information from the inputStream in an internal buffer, so the inputStream's position is further along than where the parser is at.

Any ideas on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So after looking around for quite a bit, I don't think there's a clean way to do this with the jsonParser.
I ended up implementing a reader for a general InputStream, that looked for '{' and '}' (of course taking in to account nested objects), and parsed out the underlying object through ObjectMapper from the retrieved byte array.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something like this

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "r");
InputStream inputStream = Channels.newInputStream(file.getChannel());
file.seek(byteLocationToSkipTo); //This allows you to set file pointer to this location
JsonParser parser = new JsonFactory().createParser(inputStream);
Map<String, Object> map = parser.readValueAs(Metadata.class);
```